# MSBuild copies dependencies when absolute path is specified and ignores when relative

Tags: .net, msbuild, msbuild-4.0

I try to build `.csproj` that references some projects in solution. These references are marked with `CopyLocal=False`. And this is the desired behavior.

I build it for CI using MSBuild, so I set output folder via `/p:OutputPath="some output dir"`. I also set `/p:SolutionDir="path to the solution"` to correctly resolve some NuGet references.

The problem is: when I specify OutputPath with absolute path to the output directory (like `d:\solution\build\buildgroupsubfolder`), then MSBuild copies every dependency into output directory, I don't know why it is doing so. And if I specify output path with relative path (like `..\..\..\..\..\build\buildgroupsubfolder`) then MSBuild correctly handles `CopyLocal=false` and doesn't copy references to output directory.

We had some nesting in our solution, projects are divided into groups, so we want them to be build into sub folders. And I want to be able to specify build path relative to base build path and not to path of project itself.

Why does MSBuild ignore CopyLocal=false when absolute path is specified and treats it correctly when relative path is specified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I've digged further. I've found out that MSBuild misbehaves, but not where I've though about it.

I've thought MSBuild had incorrect behavior as I described in my question. It really process `CopyLocal=false` as it should if I set `OutputDir` to relative path. And it misbehaves if I set `OutputDir` to absolute path. I found the answer in MSDN that says:

> OutputPath - Specifies the path to the output directory, **relative to
>   the project directory**, for example, "bin\Debug".

So in fact MSBuild should warn me or even fail when I set `OutputPath` to absolute path, but it doesn't. That's why I was under impression that absolute path is OK and there's a bug with `CopyLocal` handling. The actual bug is that MSBuild works when it should fail.

Comment: No, I haven't. I don't think they will ever consider this to be fixed. It is not critical. We've seen much more serious bugs, which were present for years. So I don't think this one even deserves being posted to Connect :)

Comment: Yeah, but since you've found the cause of your problems there're quite easy to solve. Just change absolute path to relative. I'm glad that my question and answer helped somebody :)

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue after switching my project and MSBuild from Visual Studio 2005 to Visual Studio 2010.  However, I wanted to avoid having to use relative path, so instead I switched to using the new Web Publishing Pipeline (WPP) in .NET 4.0 by adding the following to my MSBuild command line:

```
/p:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=True /p:PipelineDependsOnBuild=False
```

Now output is back to normal and still able to use absolute path in my output directory.